# Implicit form of general equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> Find, in implicit form, the general solution of the differential equation:
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{2y^4e^{2x}}{3\left(e^{2x}+7\right)^2}$$

I am struggling to make any sense of this. What I have understood is that first I need to seperate the variables then integrate but I am not sure how to seperate the variables.

The equations I have are :
dy/dx=f(x)g(y) then divide both sides by g(y) to get:
1/g(y) dy/dx=f(x)

I am just not sure which part of the equations would be the g(y) and f(x) pary.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put all the $y$ on the RHS and all the $x$ on the LHS using all four basic operations. That's separation of variables.

Comment: (or vice-versa...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=y(x)$, then
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{2y^4e^{2x}}{3\left(e^{2x}+7\right)^2},
$$
or
$$
-\frac{3}{y^4}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2e^{2x}}{\left(e^{2x}+7\right)^2},
$$
equivalently
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\big(y^{-3}\big)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{e^{2x}+7}\right),
$$
and thus
$$
y^{-3}=\frac{1}{e^{2x}+7}+c,
$$
for some real constant $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for that there are just a few steps I haven't quite understood. How did you get the d/dx(y^-3) part and then 1/e^2x +7

Comment: I added a line.

Comment: That's great thank you I also have to find the particular solution in implicit form that satisfies the condition y=2 and x=0 which i got to be c=0 so  the particular solution would be Y^-3=1/e^2x+7. How would I then find the explicit form of this particular solution?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

So, we have $$\frac{dy}{y^4}=\frac{2e^{2x}dx}{3(e^{2x}+7)^2}$$

Integrate either sides by substitute $e^{2x}+7$ with $u$